# Create a file in the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory on Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

We have created the following pipeline:

- Copy folders\files to the Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory
- Build the sqlcmd files for the DBA's to run on the DB

We have this setup and working on our onsite TFVC server. We have moved this pipeline over to ADO. The copy task works just fine, when it tries to create the sqlcmd files which arent in the directory (they will be new files) i get the following error:

> ##[error]New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "Access to the path 'd:\a\1\a\' is denied."

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Is it a user access issue or can you not create files on ado through a Powershell script?

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: How are things going? Please let us know if there is any progress.